# "to the day" VS "at this day"

Tags: adverbs

Do the following bold time adverbs mean the same? If yes do they both sound natural to you?

> - The king was crowned 150 years ago **to the day**.
> - The king was crowned 150 years ago **at this day**.

My third question is that if it is possible to omit the to be verb 'was' from the sentence above without losing any sense or making the sentence seem unidiomatic or strange?

Comment: Please  see [Q: Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer?s=0|1.6733) If you want the most from this website, I highly recommend you wait 2 or 3 days before selecting an answer. By selecting one as quickly as you do, you are hurting your chances to receive other answers, which you might judge to be even more helpful than the one you have currently selected.

Comment: "to the day" means exactly 150 years, while "on this day" refers to the date (for example July 31st, 2016). Though in this context, the date when the king was crowned would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use these sentences:

> The king was crowned 150 years ago **to the day**.
>   The king was crowned 150 years ago **on this day**.

These both mean that, on the current date 150 years ago, the king was crowned.

Generally, use *on* for dates and *at* for times:

> **On** this day 150 years ago **at** noon, ...
>   **At** 17:26 **on** June the 29th, ...

---

If you removed *was* from the sentence, it would not sound natural. In fact, it may take on an amusing and very different meaning:

> *intransitive verb*
>
> *in childbirth* :  to appear at the vaginal opening — used of the first part (as the crown of the head) of the infant to appear
>
> > *an anesthetic was given when the head crowned*

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crown)

Comment: English is an Amazing language. Thank you very much @LMS for being brief and to the point and timely responds.

Comment: But don't take the stuff below the line too seriously: nobody, except perhaps a midwife, would infer the childbirth meaning. Everybody would assume you just meant "was crowned".